# Missing something small, eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm getting the wrong eigenvector, would appreciate some help since I'm almost going mad here. I've got the eigenvalue $ \lambda= i$. My matrix looks like this $$\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1-\lambda&-1\\
2&-1-\lambda\
\\\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{rr}
1-i&-1\\
2&-1-i\
\\\end{array}\right].$$

I get the eigenvector $$\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1\\
1+i\
\\\end{array}\right],$$but the correct eigenvector (according to teacher) is $$\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1+i\\
2\
\\\end{array}\right].$$

Answer (score 2):

If you apply $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\2&-1\end{bmatrix}$ to your vector, you obtain $\begin{bmatrix}-i\\1-i\end{bmatrix}=-i\begin{bmatrix}-i\\1-i\end{bmatrix}$, so you found an eigenvector for the other (conjugate) eigenvalue $-i$.  And letting $x=1$, you should have obtained $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1-i\end{bmatrix}$ as eigenvector for $i$ (your teacher's solution is $1+i$ times this).

Comment: Hi, I don't understand how $\begin{bmatrix}-i\\1-i\end{bmatrix}=-i\begin{bmatrix}-i\\1-i\end{bmatrix}$. Isn't $(-i)*(-i)=-1?$

Comment: @Hagen : Typo: $\begin{bmatrix}-i\\1-i\end{bmatrix}=-i\begin{bmatrix}1\\1+i\end{bmatrix}$